# How to rename filename with ' or ? in file name?

Tags: command-line, files, rename, special-characters

I have a problem renaming a file that I'm not even sure which special characters I have in the file. I'm using CentOS 6 64bit.

When I `ls` the file:

```
Giko Suzo San?e - Ep1.avi
```

but when view it in FTP:

```
Giko Suzo San’e - Ep1.avi
```

When I try to `mv` it:

```
[root@server ]# mv 'Giko Suzo San?e - Ep1.avi' 'Giko Suzo Sane - Ep1.avi' mv: cannot stat `Giko Suzo San?e - Ep1.avi': No such file or directory
```

I also tried renaming it in FTP using FlashFXP. I get:

```
[L] 550 Giko Suzo San’e - Ep1.avi: No such file or directory Rename Failure!
```

How can I rename with this problem?

Comment: It's probably not actually a question mark. Try `printf '"%s"\n' ./Giko Suzo San*Ep1.avi` to see what it is. And if that only returns one result do `printf 'mv "%s" ./Giko_Suzo_San.Ep1.avi\n' ./Giko Suzo San*Ep1.avi | . /dev/stdin`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `\` before the character `?` so it is consider as a normal character in the name of the file and not a special character to be interpreted.

The command would then be:

```
mv Giko\ Suzo\ San\?e\ -\ Ep1.avi 'Giko Suzo Sane - Ep1.avi'
```

EDIT: following discussion in comments, this line did the trick:

```
mv Giko\ Suzo\ Sa*\ -\ Ep1.avi 'Giko Suzo Sane - Ep1.avi'
```

Comment: Yep tried that got this error mv: cannot stat `Giko Suzo San\\?e - Ep1.avi': No such file or directory

Comment: @Laurent If quotes(single or double) are used in the filename there is no need of \ before ?.  mv 'Giko Suzo San?e - Ep1.avi' newfilename or mv Giko\ Suzo\ San\?e\ -\ Ep1.avi newfilename can be used

Comment: `mv 'Giko Suzo Sa* - Ep1.avi'` didn't work

`'Giko Suzo San?e - Ep1.avi' didn't work either. I think was name using some other language that unix can not recognize.

Comment: As the problem seems to be the ? which s not recognized as a simple ? (otherwise it should work), maybe you can try using: `mv Giko\ Suzo\ Sa*\ -\ Ep1.avi 'Giko Suzo Sane - Ep1.avi'`

Comment: Holy cow that last line work. Thank you so much. Been tearing my hair out for hours. :P

Comment: Hm how do I pick this answer as the one that's working? I can't seem to upvote cause not enough reputation..

Comment: I have update my answer above. You may not be able to upvote a comment due to your reputation (and maybe not be able to upvote an answer) but there should be an accept button on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Auto-complete often fixes problems like this:

```
mv Giko<tab> "Giko Suzo San’e - Ep1.avi"
```

Comment: I tried auto-complete with tab but it wouldn't do anything, it work for other file but this one. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @user64168 Probably because the file name is in a different encoding from the one in the shell where you tried this, causing the shell to see an invalid character.

Comment: Right, this must in fact be a __unicode__ character that only *looks* like an ordinary "apostrophe".